# How to use Twilio to send a message to my phone without getting the following error?

Tags: python

```
from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient

  client = TwilioRestClient("<ID>", "<ID>")

  client.messages.create(from_='+18103394473',
                       to='+8106241057',
                       body='Ahoy from Twilio!')
```

## Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "send_sms.py", line 1, in <module>
    from twilio.rest import TwilioRestClient
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twilio/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>

    from .rest.exceptions import TwilioRestException
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twilio/rest/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>

    from .base import set_twilio_proxy
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twilio/rest/base.py", line 6, in <module>

    from twilio.rest.resources import Connection
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twilio/rest/resources/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>

    from .util import (
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twilio/rest/resources/util.py", line 1, in <module>

    import datetime
  File "/Users/JaylanSnelson/Desktop/python/python_practice/datetime.py", line 2, in <module>

    now = datetime.now()
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'now'
```

Comment: You need to use `datetime.datetime.now()` instead of `datetime.now()`

Comment: @Keatinge That is understandable, but, I never added datetime.now() to my code, so I am curious as to why i am getting this as my result

Comment: Look like your anaconda version is python2, and the code from twilio is python3

Comment: @Keatinge that worked, thanks!